# Create Conditional column in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a calculated column which is as shown in line 1 but is 0 otherwise

```
 openOptions['Cash Reserve'] =  (openOptions['Quantity'] * openOptions['Strike'] * 100)
 openOptions['Cash Reserve'] = 0 if (openOptions['OptionType'] == 'C') else openOptions['Cash Reserve']
```

I get an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), which is like an if-then-else statement for numpy/Pandas, as follows:

```
openOptions['Cash Reserve'] = np.where(openOptions['OptionType'] == 'C',
                                       0,
                                       openOptions['Cash Reserve'])
```

Alternatively, as your `Cash Reserve` column has already been set up and you modify it to 0 only under a condition, you can also use [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) :

```
openOptions.loc[openOptions['OptionType'] == 'C', 'Cash Reserve'] = 0
```

Or even further simplified,  as follows:

```
openOptions['Cash Reserve'][openOptions['OptionType'] == 'C'] = 0
```